# Shared Preference value is not updated reopen app

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

> Initially password is static like(0000).change password using shared   preference its working and password is changed.When I have re-open application again its showing static password("0000").Could you please help me.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private TextView password_view;
private EditText Edit_password;
private Button bt;
String Default_password="0000";
SharedPreferences sh_Pref;
SharedPreferences.Editor toEdit;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    password_view = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pw_view);
    Edit_password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.old_pw);
    bt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt);
    password_view.setText(Default_password);
    bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Default_password = Edit_password.getText().toString();
            sharedPrefernces();
        }
    });
}

public void sharedPrefernces(){
    sh_Pref = getSharedPreferences("PASS_WORD",MODE_PRIVATE);
    toEdit = sh_Pref.edit();
    toEdit.putString("PASSWORD", Default_password);
    toEdit.commit();
    password_view.setText(Default_password);
}
```

Comment: *Shared Preference value is not updated reopen app* it's prolly because there is no code for reading the pasword from SP

Comment: String value = sh_Pref.getString("PASSWORD", "");
        password_view.setText(value); like this??

Comment: Have you got solution